# Clustering text documents using scikit-learn kmeans in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I need to implement [scikit-learn's kMeans](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/document_clustering.html#example-document-clustering-py) for clustering text documents. The [example code](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/document_clustering.html#example-document-clustering-py) works fine as it is but takes some 20newsgroups data as input. I want to use the same code for clustering a list of documents as shown below:

```
documents = ["Human machine interface for lab abc computer applications",
             "A survey of user opinion of computer system response time",
             "The EPS user interface management system",
             "System and human system engineering testing of EPS",
             "Relation of user perceived response time to error measurement",
             "The generation of random binary unordered trees",
             "The intersection graph of paths in trees",
             "Graph minors IV Widths of trees and well quasi ordering",
             "Graph minors A survey"]
```

What changes do i need to do in [kMeans example code](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/document_clustering.html#example-document-clustering-py) to use this list as input? (Simply taking 'dataset = documents' doesn't work)

Comment: the link you provided doesnt work

Answer (score 77, accepted):

This is a simpler example:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import adjusted_rand_score

documents = ["Human machine interface for lab abc computer applications",
             "A survey of user opinion of computer system response time",
             "The EPS user interface management system",
             "System and human system engineering testing of EPS",
             "Relation of user perceived response time to error measurement",
             "The generation of random binary unordered trees",
             "The intersection graph of paths in trees",
             "Graph minors IV Widths of trees and well quasi ordering",
             "Graph minors A survey"]
```

#### vectorize the text i.e. convert the strings to numeric features

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
```

#### cluster documents

```
true_k = 2
model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=1)
model.fit(X)
```

#### print top terms per cluster clusters

```
print("Top terms per cluster:")
order_centroids = model.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]
terms = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
for i in range(true_k):
    print "Cluster %d:" % i,
    for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
        print ' %s' % terms[ind],
    print
```

If you want to have a more visual idea of how this looks like see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28205420/1330293).

Comment: thank u but it gives me syntax errors in print commands at end ='' and print() ... how do i make it work? :s

Comment: Oh, that is because I am Python 3, I edited my answer.

Comment: @elyase: how can this code be altered to get the central sentences per cluster?

Comment: @Crista23, it is not directly possible. First sentences are converted to numeric vectors  (Bag of Words representation) and then clustered but this transformation does not preserve the word order (among other issues) so you can't go back from central vector to sentence. You have to get creative to get 'something' back from the centroid.

Comment: Not clear how to clustering sentences instead of words in this case.
The words clustering works fine in this example, but sentences clustering not.

Comment: @elyase ,how do i store the results?,mydict={}
for k in range(2,10):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = k, max_iter = 300).fit(x)
    labels = kmeans.labels_
    label_df = pd.DataFrame(labels.tolist(),columns=['class'])
    new_df = pd.concat((harsh,label_df),axis = 1)
    #new_df.to_csv("result{}.csv".format(k))
    order_centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]
    
    for i in range(k):
        for ind in order_centroids[i,:12]:
            mydict.update({i:(terms[ind])})