# plot a document tfidf 2D graph

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, k-means

I would like to plot a 2d graph with the x-axis as term and y-axis as TFIDF score (or document id) for my list of sentences. I used scikit learn's fit_transform() to get the scipy matrix but i do not know how to use that matrix to plot the graph. I am trying to get a plot to see how well my sentences can be classified using kmeans.

Here is the output of `fit_transform(sentence_list)`:

**(document id, term number) tfidf score**

```
(0, 1023)   0.209291711271
(0, 924)    0.174405532933
(0, 914)    0.174405532933
(0, 821)    0.15579574484
(0, 770)    0.174405532933
(0, 763)    0.159719994016
(0, 689)    0.135518787598
```

Here is my code:

```
sentence_list=["Hi how are you", "Good morning" ...]
vectorizer=TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, stop_words='english', decode_error='ignore')
vectorized=vectorizer.fit_transform(sentence_list)
num_samples, num_features=vectorized.shape
print "num_samples:  %d, num_features: %d" %(num_samples,num_features)
num_clusters=10
km=KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters, init='k-means++',n_init=10, verbose=1)
km.fit(vectorized)
PRINT km.labels_   # Returns a list of clusters ranging 0 to 10
```

Thanks,

Comment: Does the following work for you? It should if you're only looking at a simple 2D plot. http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/simple_plot.html

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When you use Bag of Words, each of your sentences gets represented in a high dimensional space of length equal to the vocabulary. If you want to represent this in 2D you need to reduce the dimension, for example using PCA with two components:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', 
                                      categories=['alt.atheism', 'sci.space'])
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
])        
X = pipeline.fit_transform(newsgroups_train.data).todense()

pca = PCA(n_components=2).fit(X)
data2D = pca.transform(X)
plt.scatter(data2D[:,0], data2D[:,1], c=data.target)
plt.show()              #not required if using ipython notebook
```

[image: data2d]

Now you can for example calculate and plot the cluster enters on this data:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(X)
centers2D = pca.transform(kmeans.cluster_centers_)

plt.hold(True)
plt.scatter(centers2D[:,0], centers2D[:,1], 
            marker='x', s=200, linewidths=3, c='r')
plt.show()              #not required if using ipython notebook
```

[image]

Comment: can i just use tfidfvectorizer instead of doing countvectorizer then tfidftransformer?
Will the code for pipeline look like this: `pipeline = Pipeline([('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer())])`?

Comment: im getting an error for `plt.scatter(data2D[:,0], data2D[:,1], c=data.target)` specifically `c=data.target`. If i want the colors of the scatter plots to be tuned to the colors of the clusters discovered by kmeans, what should i use in place of `data.target`? `kmeans.label_`? #this returns a list.

Comment: The Pipeline is used to execute several transformers serially. If you have only one you don't need the Pipeline, just use the transformer directly.

Comment: @elyase could you please look into this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/50334915/2508414

Comment: Instead of data.target use newsgroups_train.target

Answer (score 2):

Just assign a variable to the labels and use that to denote color. ex 
`km = Kmeans().fit(X) 
clusters = km.labels_.tolist()`
then `c=clusters`

Answer (score 2):

In the previous answer, there are some issues. So I tweak those issues and pushed the code here.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', 
                                      categories=['alt.atheism', 'sci.space'])

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
])        
X = pipeline.fit_transform(newsgroups_train.data).todense()

pca = PCA(n_components=2).fit(X)
data2D = pca.transform(X)
plt.scatter(data2D[:,0], data2D[:,1], c=newsgroups_train.target)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
## Nearest neighbour
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(X)
centers2D = pca.transform(kmeans.cluster_centers_)

# plt.hold(True)
plt.scatter(data2D[:,0], data2D[:,1], c=newsgroups_train.target)
plt.scatter(centers2D[:,0], centers2D[:,1], 
            marker='x', s=200, linewidths=3, c='r')
plt.show()
```

[image]