# How to fix color of plot display 2d python data from tf idf?

Tags: python, text, mining

I have tried code from this link [plot a document tfidf 2D graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28160335/plot-a-document-tfidf-2d-graph)

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, 
TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pipeline = Pipeline([
('vect', CountVectorizer()),
('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
])        
X = pipeline.fit_transform(x_test).todense()

pca = PCA(n_components=2).fit(X)
data2D = pca.transform(X)
plt.scatter(data2D[:,0], data2D[:,1],c=x_test)
plt.show()
```

That's code is worked if I delete c=x_test in the last line, but the color is same just one color, if I add `c=x_test` its say error `ValueError: c of shape (444L,) not acceptable as a color sequence for x with size 444, y with size 444`

How to fix the code so that the color should be 6 classes or categories?

Comment: Where's 6 coming from? Have one of `X`, `x_test`, `data2D` ended up in 6 categories? Where?

Comment: @doctorlove 6 is the number of class or categories in my dataset

Comment: Sure. I wondered if you had a variable in there with the classes? Use that for the colors.

Comment: Can you share your `x_test`?