# predicting closest cluster sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I was reading this stackoverflow and had a further question. Once the clusters have been made, is it possible to determine what cluster a new sentence will fall into ?

[Clustering text documents using scikit-learn kmeans in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27889873/clustering-text-documents-using-scikit-learn-kmeans-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just use the [`predict`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans.predict) method. Continuing the example from the referenced question

```
X_new = vectorizer.transform([sentence])
y_new = model.predict(X_new)
```