# doc2vec How to cluster DocvecsArray

Tags: python, machine-learning, k-means, word2vec, doc2vec

I've patched the following code from examples I've found over the web:

```
# gensim modules
from gensim import utils
from gensim.models.doc2vec import LabeledSentence
from gensim.models import Doc2Vec
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

# random
from random import shuffle

# classifier

class LabeledLineSentence(object):
    def __init__(self, sources):
        self.sources = sources

        flipped = {}

        # make sure that keys are unique
        for key, value in sources.items():
            if value not in flipped:
                flipped[value] = [key]
            else:
                raise Exception('Non-unique prefix encountered')

    def __iter__(self):
        for source, prefix in self.sources.items():
            with utils.smart_open(source) as fin:
                for item_no, line in enumerate(fin):
                    yield LabeledSentence(utils.to_unicode(line).split(), [prefix + '_%s' % item_no])

    def to_array(self):
        self.sentences = []
        for source, prefix in self.sources.items():
            with utils.smart_open(source) as fin:
                for item_no, line in enumerate(fin):
                    self.sentences.append(LabeledSentence(utils.to_unicode(line).split(), [prefix + '_%s' % item_no]))
        return self.sentences

    def sentences_perm(self):
        shuffle(self.sentences)
        return self.sentences

sources = {'test.txt' : 'DOCS'}
sentences = LabeledLineSentence(sources)

model = Doc2Vec(min_count=1, window=10, size=100, sample=1e-4, negative=5, workers=8)
model.build_vocab(sentences.to_array())

for epoch in range(10):
    model.train(sentences.sentences_perm())

print(model.docvecs)
```

my test.txt file contains a paragraph per line.

The code runs fine and generates DocvecsArray for each line of text

my goal is to have an output like so:

cluster 1: [DOC_5,DOC_100,...DOC_N]
cluster 2: [DOC_0,DOC_1,...DOC_N]

I have found the [following Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27889873/clustering-text-documents-using-scikit-learn-kmeans-in-python), but the output is:

cluster 1: [word,word...word]
cluster 2: [word,word...word]

How can I alter the code and get document clusters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So it looks like you're almost there.

You are outputting a set of vectors. For the sklearn package, you have to put those into a numpy array - using the numpy.toarray() function would probably be best. [The documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_iris.html) for KMeans is really stellar and even across the whole library it's good.

A note for you is that I have had much better luck with [DBSCAN](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html#example-cluster-plot-dbscan-py) than KMeans, which are both contained in the same sklearn library. DBSCAN doesn't require you to specify how many clusters you want to have on the output.

There are well-commented code examples in both links.

Comment: cool, I'll have a look .. did you implemented document clustering?

Comment: No, but I've worked with document classification. In general it gets harder the smaller the text. Starting out, you might want to keep it to bigger texts.

Comment: http://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparing_clustering_algorithms.html

looks really interesting

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used:

```
for doc in docs:
    doc_vecs = model.infer_vector(doc.split())
# creating a matrix from list of vectors
mat = np.stack(doc_vecs)

# Clustering Kmeans
km_model = KMeans(n_clusters=5)
km_model.fit(mat)
# Get cluster assignment labels
labels = km_model.labels_

# Clustering DBScan
dbscan_model = DBSCAN()
labels = dbscan_model.fit_predict(mat)
```

Where model is the pre-trained Doc2Vec model. In my case I didn't need to cluster the same documents of the training but new documents saved in the `docs` list