# simple k-means clustering for bag of words model using python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

The input dataset looks like this:

```
{"666": ["abc",
         "xyz"],
 "888": ["xxxo",
         "xxxo"], 
 "007": ["abc"]}
```

We start by creating a bag-of-words model using the following function:

```
def associate_terms_with_user(unique_term_set, all_users_terms_dict):

    associated_value_return_dict = {}

    # consider the first user
    for user_id in all_users_terms_dict:

        # what terms *could* this user have possibly used
        this_user_zero_vector = []

        # this could be refactored somehow
        for term in  unique_term_set:
            this_user_zero_vector.extend('0')

        # what terms *did* this user use
        terms_belong_to_this_user = all_users_terms_dict.get(user_id)

        # let's start counting all the possible terms that this term in the personal
        # user list of words could correspond to... 
        global_term_element_index = 0

        # while this one term is in the range of all possible terms
        while global_term_element_index < len(unique_term_set):

            # start counting the number of terms he used
            local_term_set_item_index = 0

            # if this one term he used is still in the range of terms he used, counting them one by one
            while local_term_set_item_index < len(terms_belong_to_this_user):

                # if this one user term is the same as this one global term
                if list(unique_term_set)[global_term_element_index] == terms_belong_to_this_user[local_term_set_item_index]:

                    # increment the number of times this user used this term
                    this_user_zero_vector[global_term_element_index] = '1'

                # go to the next term for this user
                local_term_set_item_index += 1

            # go to the next term in the global list of all possible terms
            global_term_element_index += 1

        associated_value_return_dict.update({user_id: this_user_zero_vector})

    pprint.pprint(associated_value_return_dict)
```

The output of the program looks like this:

```
{'007': ['0', '0', '1'], 
 '666': ['0', '1', '1'], 
 '888': ['1', '0', '0']}
```

How could we implement a simple function to cluster those vectors based on their similarity to one another? I envisage using [k-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) and possibly scikit-learn.

I've never done that before and I don't know how, I'm new to machine learning in generally and I don't really even know where to start.

Finally `666` and `007` would probably be clustered together, and `888` would be alone in a cluster by itself, isn't it?

The full code lives [here](https://github.com/s-matthew-english/hackensack-ke-2017/blob/master/hashtag_clustering.py).

Comment: Kmeans is a good idea I think. You can see an example here: [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/document_clustering.html)

Comment: ah, cool- thank you. but I mean like- do you know how I would feed in that bag of words `dict` data structure that I have to a k-means function? do I need to change it at all first?

Comment: i will post some websites in an answer. there are some examples and answers. hope this helps

Comment: K-means does not work well on short text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kmeans is a good idea.

Some examples and code from the web:

1) Document Clustering with Python [link](http://brandonrose.org/clustering)

2) Clustering text documents using scikit-learn kmeans in Python [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27889873/clustering-text-documents-using-scikit-learn-kmeans-in-python)

3) Clustering a long list of strings (words) into similarity groups [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123060/clustering-a-long-list-of-strings-words-into-similarity-groups)

4) Kaggle post [link](https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/details/part-3-more-fun-with-word-vectors)

Comment: Which will best suit me if I had to tell categorise (based on the cluster it is present in) whether a resume falls under nursing or teaching or management type?