# Best method for long strings matching based on uniqueness in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to match a part's description to a list of similar part descriptions.

For string matching I have tried fuzzywuzzy and difflib.getclosematch() but these seem to be at the character level (i.e. for incorrect spelling, rather than at the word level).

For example:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
List = ['Adjustable linkage 6cm in width', 'for Torus laser pointer (screws short and long)', 'pineapples', 'foo', 'bar' ]
print(process.extractOne('ULTRA SHORT PEDAL LINKAGE', List)
```

Returns:`('for Torus laser pointer (screws short and long)', 86)`

Rather than: `"Adjustable linkage 6cm in width"`

Any ideas to have a more sophisticated matching system? Perhaps finding the most unique word first and seeing if that matches, then move to next word.

Thanks in advance,
Will

Comment: Please post some piece of code. See [MRE]. Have you tried to ovectorize your words and do some kmean clustering? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44886756/simple-k-means-clustering-for-bag-of-words-model-using-python

Comment: Thanks, Malo. I have looked into bag of words/clustering but Natural Language Processing is beyond me. I will try a similar approach by associating each word with a number of occurrences value. And find description based on the fewest occurrences of a word.